# FT232H/FT2232H mount as /dev/i2c-x

Tags: i2c, linux, ftdi

SBC like Raspberry have the 40 pin header which contains a I2C master. This is a accessible via /dev/i2c-0.

I would like to achieve the same thing on my linux laptop (ubuntu) using the FT232H chip. I can interface the FT232H using the pyftdi package, however it would be great if I could use the exact same thing on any linux machine that has a free usb port.

When I plug the device on my laptop(linux), I can only see that the UART is mounted to /dev/ttyUSB0. Anybody an idea how to 'mount' the I2C function of FT232H on /dev/i2c-0 (or /dev/i2c-1, -2, -3, ..)?

I don't know where to start looking, so any help is very welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: You'd need to unload the USB serial driver or get it to ignore that VID/PID and find or create and load a suitable I2C driver instead.  Today userpace solutions as you described with python are typically preferred.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, thx for quick response; the unload I get it, FT232H work either as UART, either as I2C (or SPI,...) but not both at the same time.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, can you elaborate why userspace solution are preferred?

Comment: Flexibility and portability, typically

Comment: thx, is there a gnu-c or gnu-c++ equivalent to pyftdi?

Comment: There are libftdi and libmpsse, one is the current (maybe the later) and the other deprectated, or I might be remembering that backwards.

Comment: Thx, I'll have a look at this: https://github.com/devttys0/libmpsse will come back later.

Comment: To add to the user-space argument: User space solution do not require any device drivers (except for a generic USB driver provided by the operating system). So it's easier to implement and it can even be implemented in a way portable across operating systems. And the user does not need any special rights to install a device driver. The device driver for FTDI chips is especially problematic as it limits the chip to UART only, disabling the I2C, SPI etc. features. Device drivers are ok for officially standardized USB protocols such as keyboard, mice, external disks, cameras etc.